# Purpose of "consider_all_requests_local" in config/environments/development.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the purpose of this Rails config setting...

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

It's set to true by default in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Thanks,

Ethan

Comment: As an aside: In rails 3 the option is `config.consider_all_requests_local=`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Non-local requests result in user-friendly error pages.  Local requests, assumed to come from developers, see a more useful error message that includes line numbers and a backtrace.  `consider_all_requests_local` allows your app to display these developer-friendly messages even when the machine making the request is remote.

Comment: The Rails default error message is only *marginally* friendly.  It also serves another purpose, though, which is to not show too much information about the internal error to outsiders who might want to use that information against you.

Comment: Could this change the response status and headers? Say, if I'm trying to return a `503` but a client is receiving a `500`?

Answer (score 7):

At development level we set:

> consider_all_requests_local set = true

because developer needs to take a look at full error showing layout/view as you can see in the image below.

[image]

But at production level, we don't need to show our internal coding bug so we set  false:

> config.consider_all_requests_local = false

[image]