# Error in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My other pages are fine but gives error "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." in bookings page.

Log details

```
    27.34.62.47 - - [12/Dec/2013:13:42:02 +0800] "GET /admin/bookings/13 HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "http://admin.wiyo.hk/admin/bookings" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
27.34.62.47 - - [12/Dec/2013:13:42:06 +0800] "GET /admin/bookings/13 HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "http://admin.wiyo.hk/admin/bookings" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
27.34.62.47 - - [12/Dec/2013:13:42:09 +0800] "GET /admin/bookings/13 HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "http://admin.wiyo.hk/admin/bookings" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
27.34.62.47 - - [12/Dec/2013:13:42:11 +0800] "GET /admin/bookings/13 HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "http://admin.wiyo.hk/admin/bookings" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
27.34.62.47 - - [12/Dec/2013:13:42:22 +0800] "POST /en/bookings/confirm HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "http://wiyo.hk/en/bookings/review" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

Comment: Where is resided the production server, what is the production server.

Comment: In development mode in ruby on rails, All pages were fine. But, when i moved to production mode, booking pages doesn't work. Production mode is hosted on VPS Centos 6.2. It says "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Comment: I mean, is this VPS? Which web-server, and rack-server do you used?

Comment: Can you post the actual error that's being printed to your log?

Comment: Yes this is VPS, apache passenger is the web server on cent os..

Comment: Above were the information I got in log, There are no other errors shown.

Comment: When I switched back to webbrick again, works on :3000. All are fine but gives error on boooking page when i stopped webbrick.

Comment: You might want to enable a full backtrace in prod and post to this thread - check out how to do that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373089/purpose-of-consider-all-requests-local-in-config-environments-development-rb

Comment: what's in your log/production.log on the server?

Comment: There is noting in log/production.log It says it is 0kb that means I dont have anything in production.log