# Rails ActionMailer preview in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am using rails 4.1.1 and ActionMailer::Preview for previewing emails. In development environment everything is working excellent.

But in production environment the preview routes are not accessible. I store the previews in test/mailers/previews/

Is is possible to enable them for production?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to this:

```
config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
```

you will also need to set

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

in your environment for the preview routes to be accessible. This has other implications as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/373135/1599045) so you likely **don't want to enable this in production**. However, if you have a custom environment that's not `development`, the combination of those two should get things working.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

The original question was for rails 4.1.1, which doesn't have `config.action_mailer.show_previews` available. To get ActionMailer previews working in non-development environments in rails 4.1.1, you need to first add some routes to `config/routes.rb` (in this case, my environment is named `custom`):

```
if Rails.env.custom?
  get '/rails/mailers'               => "rails/mailers#index"
  get 'rails/mailers/download/*path' => "rails/mailers#download"
  get '/rails/mailers/*path'         => "rails/mailers#preview"
end
```

Then you need to autoload the libraries needed in your environment's config file (in my case, `config/environments/custom.rb`):

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path ||= defined?(Rails.root) ? "#{Rails.root}/test/mailers/previews" : nil
config.autoload_paths += [config.action_mailer.preview_path]
```

This seems to perform the same task as `config.action_mailer.show_previews` does.

As with 4.2, you will still need to adjust the local request configuration as above depending on whether your custom environment is being used locally or on a server.

Comment: I've had to switch `config.cache_classes = false` in order to get it working in 4.2.2, untested in any other release.

Comment: A word of warning that you should absolutely NOT set `config.consider_all_requests_local` as this will dump error messages to the browser, the same as you see while in development mode. You definitely don't want to do this in a production environment that has regular users out in the world. See the "To do it without open a big security hole" answer in this thread!

Answer (score 15):

To do it without opening a big security hole:

### production.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.preview_path ||= defined?(Rails.root) ? "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailer_previews" : nil
  config.autoload_paths += [config.action_mailer.preview_path]

  routes.append do
    get '/rails/mailers'         => "rails/mailers#index"
    get '/rails/mailers/*path'   => "rails/mailers#preview"
  end
end

class ::Rails::MailersController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  def local_request?
    true
  end
  private
  def authenticate_admin!
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I get adding the `before_filter` and overriding the `local_request?` method for the `::Rails::MailersController` class. But the changes for the  `MyApp::Application.configure` section seem unnecessary. Seems like the secure way would be to set `config.action_mailer.show_previews = true` and then use the bottom part of what you suggested. Can you help me understand about the paths and routes?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to enable previews in production by `config.action_mailer.show_previews = true` as the best answer says.

I just want to add how you can render previews in iframe within your own admin area, eg. in [active admin](https://gist.github.com/Lukom/a0135204de7e8a5eedaf45a0952eedc5) (Rails 5.1)

And also I found out that it is not so hard to [write your own email previews administration](https://gist.github.com/Lukom/ac5116e308c4a32e46f6827744c88991), and don't use rails standard previews at all. You can then add your own features such as changing preview parameters or *Send* button to see this email in your phone.

Answer (score 2):

From Rails 4.2 you can use the flag in production.rb (or other custom enviroment):

```
config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
```

I haven't found anything similar in Rails 4.1.

**Update**:
If Rspec used, for example, there will be need to add the path:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews"
```

Default path is "#{Rails.root}/test/mailers/previews".

And **no need to touch** config.consider_all_requests_local

Comment: The application responds with "For security purposes, this information is only available to local requests." if we try to execute it in the server

Comment: you should also add `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Comment: I'm on Rails 5 and this one setting worked for me. The mail previews are available to the entire world, however. We'll have to come up with something to block non-admin users. Note that it is a very bad idea to set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in a production environment—users will see the internal stack trace and error messages rather than your 404 or 500 page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did for Rails 5.2:

> `production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
  config.action_mailer.preview_path ||= defined?(Rails.root) ? "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews" : nil

  class ::Rails::MailersController
    include ::ApplicationController::Authorization
    before_action :require_admin
  end
```

Assuming your `ApplicationController::Authorization` module has the code for `require_admin`. I preferred this approach rather than rewriting my authorization code. Remembering to include the `::` in front was tricky, because saying `include ApplicationController::...` will look within the `Rails::MailersController` namespace.