# Rails in API only mode returning HTML Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm a bit confused by the output in my rails console, and that a Rails API only project is returning HTML errors. I have a controller that is throwing an ActiveRecord Validation Error. In my console output I see:

```
  ↳ app/controllers/v1/users/accounts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 324ms (ActiveRecord: 30.9ms | Allocations: 15443)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)):

app/controllers/v1/users/accounts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

But in the response I'm getting a huge chunk of HTML. These routes are wrapped in `scope :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do` so I would expect the response format to be JSON. Is this expected behavior?

Yes I plan to catch errors and handle them, but I'm confused why a rails API only application would return *any* html.

Rails 7.0.2.2
Ruby 3.0.3

Comment: You probaly shouldn't be using `create!` or `save!` in your controller. Invalid user input is not an exceptional event and shouldn't be treated as such - the bang methods should be reserved for contexts where it should not be expected to fail, or inside of a transaction to trigger a rollback. There are also better ways to dry the code like for example using the Responders gem instead of `rescue_from`.

Comment: Could the HTML response be that you're in the development environment and that its the default error page being rendered?  That behavior is determined by [`config.consider_all_requests_local`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373089/purpose-of-consider-all-requests-local-in-config-environments-development-rb) and its still the default in an api only app.

Comment: @max thanks for the advice, that is not how my production controllers looks. I was intentionally causing an error for this example. You are exactly right, `consider_all_requests_local` was the issue. Setting that to false gives me a JSON error response. Weird they would still spit out HTML in development on an API only application. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0):

As @max pointed out, HTML errors were being returned due to `consider_all_requests_local` being set to `true` in `development.rb`. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373089/purpose-of-consider-all-requests-local-in-config-environments-development-rb). Seems counterintuitive to return HTML responses in API only mode, alas setting it to false will correct the issue.